# WebDriver exiting for

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with Selenium WebDriver exiting the for loop after performing only once. Presumably it's the problem with getting content and the loop starting before the page is loaded. Is there a possibility to make webdriver wait until the page is loaded?

```
List<WebElement> albums = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    albums = driver.findElements(By.className("album_title"));

    for (WebElement we : albums) {

        we.click();
        if (driver.findElement(By.id("delete_album_prompt")).isDisplayed()) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("delete_album_prompt")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("delete_album_yes")).click();
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Thread.sleep(20000); Use this method before the loop starts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for an element to be loaded.

In [Selenium documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example), they provide the following example that will wait until the google page is loaded. In this case it's waiting, at most 10 seconds, for the title element to be loaded and have a specified value.

```
// Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
// Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
       return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, where `TimeOut` is defined as `int` value.

```
Wait wait = DriverManager.getWait(Driver.TIMEOUT);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
```

Basically wait for an element to get loaded. This is better than providing sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I think , You are checking the Item in the List

```
driver.findElement(By.id("delete_album_prompt")).isDisplayed()
```

which will return true for 1st item, but for remaining items in the list it will return false since those item will not getting displayed. That's why its exiting from the Loop.

You can use following function for checking item Present there in `if`

```
private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By by){
try{
driver.findElement(by);
return true;
}catch(NoSuchElementException e){
return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using - wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.id("id")));  it works !